# PostgreSQL: Add a numerical number of seconds to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, intervals, timedelta

## The problem

Consider a table with two fields: a timestamp dubbed `creation_time` and a integer number of seconds dubbed `expiration_time_seconds`. Hence,

```sql
SELECT creation_time, expiration_time_seconds FROM items;
```

Gives:

```sql
       creation_time        | expiration_time_seconds
----------------------------+-------------------------
 2014-11-18 05:38:05.368598 |                    3600
 2014-11-19 21:38:10.380777 |                 2592000
 2014-11-19 21:41:28.152839 |                    3600
 2014-11-18 17:15:11.501205 |                    3600
 2014-11-19 21:43:38.815154 |                    3600
 ...
```

How do I add the expiration time to the creation time to get the expiration time?

## What I've tried

Creating an interval from a constant text is easy:

```sql
SELECT creation_time+interval '3600 seconds' FROM question;
```

Which gives:

```sql
          ?column?
----------------------------
 2014-11-18 06:38:05.368598
 2014-11-19 22:38:10.380777
 2014-11-19 22:41:28.152839
 ...
```

But I failed to use a custom text or an integer as the interval.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply a constant interval with the `expiration_time_seconds` column:

```sql
SELECT creation_time+interval '1 second'*expiration_time_seconds FROM items;
```

Credit: [Re: Create interval using column value?](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9636.1098673912@sss.pgh.pa.us), PostgreSQL forums